# Vertx and JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, platform, vert.x

Is there a way to use JavaFX with Vert.x application platform ? I am tryin to build simple application that uses verte.x server and JavaFx client communicating via Vert.x Even Bus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no reason you cant. One way would be to expose the EventBus via a websocket (or use the SockJS Bridge) and connect to that from your JavaFX client. Some links to get you started:

**Client Side**

- http://architects.dzone.com/articles/sample-java-web-socket-client

**Server Side**

- http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#websockets

Good luck!

Comment: Some more links, for client side: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-websocket-client-api.html and http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-fallback-sockjs-client. For Server Side http://vertx.io/core_manual_java.html#sockjs-eventbus-bridge